# Having both primary key and foreign key in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key

Should I both have a primary key and a foreign key in the same table?

Eg: one to one

I have a **User table** and a **Address table**.

Each User has one address.

Should I only add a foreign key in the **Address table** that points to the primary key in the **User table**?

Or should I also create a primary key in the **Address table**?

**Update:**

Each User CAN have a address. So not all users will have a address. If a user decides to enter his/hers address. Then the address will end up in the Address table

Comment: It's a good practice to have a primary key in every table, even if it has foreign keys to other tables.

Comment: If it truly is a one-to-one relationship you can make the primary key of the Address table be the user key. It can serve as both a foreign and primary key, but it does limit flexibility in your schema.

Comment: How about a `Composite primary key` (User,Address) in a single table since you have `one to one` relationship

Comment: If the user and address are truly 1 to 1, why have an address table at all?

Comment: Sorry I missed something. Each User CAN have a address. So not all users will have a address. If a user decides to enter his/hers address. Then the address will end up in the Address table

Comment: If it is a one to one relation why not keeping address data inside customer table?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, the first question is why you need an address table at all if they are truly 1 to 1?

That aside, I would reverse the relationship.  You state that:

```
Each User has one address.
```

If that is an accurate description of the model, the User table should reference the address table, and not the other way around.  An address *could* have multiple users.  So the user table would have a foreign key column that points to the address table.

Regarding other comments and answers, I agree that it's a good practice for nearly every table to have a primary key.  There are certainly exceptions, but it's a good rule of thumb.

Comment: It's good practice to separate information from tables creating one-one relationships - see [Third Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Comment: Sorry I missed something. Each User CAN have a address. So not all users will have a address. If a user decides to enter his/hers address. Then the address will end up in the Address table

Comment: @RobFarr: TNF does not say move 1-1 relationships into separate tables.  If an address is tied to a user directly, it should be in the same table--this is what TNF states.  If an address can be shared (one to many), then the address should be in a separate table.

Comment: @user2722667: if the address is truly a part of the user--in other words, it is not shared and changes with the user, the best option would still be to store it in the user table and make the fields nullable.  If the address can be shared or must be in a separate table, make it a nullable reference (foreign key).

Comment: I think this answers the question at hand. It is true, that with a one-to-one relationship you actually would not need to have a separate table for addresses. I would keep them separate nevertheless having the fk in the addresses table. That way, it's less effort when you decide to change the model later, say having a billing address and the address of residence.

Answer (score 0):

I would recogmend you to use a primary key in each table. It could happen, that 2 users live in the same house. Just to be safe...

Comment: If 2 users live in the same house it wouldn't be a one-one relationship, as per the original question's description.

Comment: i mean if you have the same adress twice in adress table, there would be complications - use a primary key

Comment: I see this mistake made a lot with addresses--two users share an address entity.  Then one of them moves to a new address, so the row gets updated, and the system effectively moves both users to the new address.  It's rarely useful to have a separate address table unless a person or business can have multiple addresses.

Answer (score 0):

All tables should have a primary key. The foreign key points to a primary key in another table to establish the relationship.